# Classifying the epimorphisms in the category of normal topological spaces and continuous maps

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

**Question:** classify all epimorphisms in the full category $\mathcal{N}$ of Top on the normal topological spaces. Hint: you may find it useful to invoke Urysohn's lemma.

**My work:** I have no hypothesis so I'll just go of the definitions and see if something pops up. A morphism $f$ is epi if $hf = gf \implies h = g$ for all $g, h$. Let us say $X \xrightarrow{f} Y \xrightarrow{g, h} Z$. An epimorphism in Set is in particular an epimorphism in $\mathcal{N}$, so the surjective maps must be epimorphisms.

Suppose $g$ and $h$ are not equal. Then there is some $y \in Y$ such that $g(y) \neq h(y)$.

I'm not sure how to apply Urysohn's lemma, as the preimages of a point in $z$ under $g$ and $h$ aren't necessarily disjoint and those are the only non-trivial guaranteed closed sets in $Z$.

Comment: "so the epimorphisms must be at least surjective" is backwards--rather, the conclusion is that at least all surjective maps are epimorphisms.

Comment: Does normal include Hausdorff?

Comment: @PaulFrost  Yes. Normal means points are closed and any two closed subsets can be covered with two open disjoint subsets each containing one of the two closed subsets (so in particular the Hausdorff property is satisfied).

Comment: @PaulFrost and M.Van, "normal" may mean **only** that the disjoint closed sets are separated by their open neighborhoods. Then "normal+$T_1''\ $ means $\ T_4.$ If I remember well (and I am supposed to remember it), Engelking's classic on General Topology does not assume that *normal* implies *closed singletons*.

Comment: @WlodAA That is why I asked. Some authors define "normal" as in your comment, other authors additionally require $T_1$. Engelking is one of the latter ;-) See p. 62 of his great book.

Comment: @PaulFrost, Richard Engelking in his "General Topology" is consistent -- among classes of topological spaces, there are: $\ T_0\ T_1\ T_2,\ $ then $\ T_3=\mbox{regular} + T_1,\ $ and $\ T_{3\frac 12}\ $ and $\ T_4=\mbox{normal}+T_1,\ $ etc.

Comment: @PaulFrost, "p. 62 of his great book." -- Which edition? :) -- I am the only Polish topologist who didn't get a free copy of the monograph from the author. First, I was not around, then he delayed because he wanted to present me with the new edition but the ugly politics (outside the mathematics!) kicked in hence nobody had time to think about such trivial matters. But he had a very nice attitude in each dimension. O-la-la-la...

Comment: @WlodAA It is from 1977. I bought it ~ 1980 at a price of DM154,75 (today = 79,12 €) which was very expensive at that time. It was and is worth paying every penny. Quote from this edition: "A topological space $X$ is called a *$T_4$-space*, or a *normal space*, if it is a $T_1$-space and for every pair of disjoint closed subspaces ...".

Comment: @PaulFrost, wow, thank you, I stand corrected. (I used to have my own copy years ago but I moved a lot and lost a lot of my books which was a bit sad).

Comment: @WlodAA The latest edition seems to be from 1989. See http://www.heldermann.de/SSPM/SSPM06/sspm06.htm. Probably Engelking changed the definition between 1977 and 1989. And 1989 was a very good year for Poland and the world ... and for Germany on November 9, 1989.

Comment: @WlodAA It wasn't easy at that time to gain access to literature published in the former Socialist Bloc. However, there was bookstore "Buchhandlung Harri Deutsch " whose owner must be have had special relations and offered a great variety of "inaccessible" books. Good luck for me - and good luck for everybody that those days are over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once read somewhere that the epimorphisms in the category of Hausdorff spaces are precisely those continuous maps with dense image. So as a conjecture I began with that and here’s a solution (it turns out the epimorphisms are precisely the continuous maps with dense image by the way):
Suppose $f$ is epi but $f$ does not have dense image. Then there is some $y \in Y$ such that $y \notin \overline{f(X)}$. Urysohn’s lemma now gives that there exists a continuous map $g : Y \mapsto [0,1]$ such that $g(y)=0$ and $g(z)=1$ for all $z \in \overline{f(X)}$. In particular $g(f(x))=1$ for all $x \in X$. So
$$g \circ f =1 \circ f$$
where $1$ is the constant $1$ function.
So $g=1$, so $0=g(y)=1$, contradiction.
We conclude the image of $f$ lies dense in $Y$.

Suppose now $f$ has dense image.
Now if $g_1,g_2: Y \rightarrow Z$ are such that they are equal on $f(X)$, $g_1$ and $g_2$ are two continuous maps that are equal on a dense subset, so if we’re lucky they are equal ;). So if we prove the following we’re done:

**Lemma** Let $h_1,h_2: A \rightarrow B$ be continuous maps between Hausdorff topological spaces that are equal on a dense subset. Then $h_1=h_2$.

**Proof**
We will show the set
$C=\{ x \in A | h_1(x) \neq h_2(x) \}$ is open in $A$, from this the result immediately follows. Since $A$ is Hausdorff, the diagonal $\Delta \subset A \times A$ is closed.
So the inverse image of $\{(x,y) | x \neq y\}$ under the composition
$$A \xrightarrow{x \mapsto (x,x)} A \times A \xrightarrow{(h_1,h_2)} A \times A$$
is open. But this inverse image is precisely $C$ and we’re done.